# How can I convert String to Map using MapStruct?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, dto, mapstruct

I have `Story` entity in my Spring Boot application. It has `String` field `storyInfo` which contains:

```
{"title":"random title", "description":"random description"}
```

For my `Story` entity I have `StoryDTO` with `map` field called `storyInfo`.
The question is: how can I convert `String` field from `Strory` into `Map` in `StoryDTO` using `MapStruct`?

Answer (score 5):

Try following code, inspired from [here](http://javadevcorner.com/mapstruct-custom-mapping-rest-operations/)

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface StoryMapper {

      @Mappings({
        @Mapping(source = "storyInfo", target = "storyInfo", qualifiedByName = "fromJsonToMap")
      })
      StoryDTO toStoryDTO(Story story);

      @Mappings({
        @Mapping(source = "storyInfo", target = "storyInfo", qualifiedByName = "fromMapToJson")
      })
      Story toStory(StoryDTO storyDTO);

      @Named("fromJsonToMap")
      default Map<String, Object> fromJsonToMap(String storyInfo) throws IOException {
        if (Objects.nonNull(storyInfo)) {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            Map<String, Double> result = objectMapper.readValue(storyInfo, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>() {});
            return result;
        }
        return null;
      }

      @Named("fromMapToJson")
      default String fromMapToJson(Map<String, Object> storyInfo) throws JsonProcessingException {
        if (Objects.nonNull(storyInfo)) {
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            String result = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(storyInfo);
            return result;
        }
        return null;
      }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Thank you guys for answers. Found the easiest solution for me by adding few manual mappers to MapStruct's `StoryMapper` interface.

```
// Manual convert to Map
default Map toMap(String text){
    Map map = new HashMap();
    try {
        map = new ObjectMapper().readValue(text, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>(){});
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return map;
}

// Manual convery from map
default String fromMap(Map map){
    return new JSONObject(map).toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The already provided [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48492474/1115491) explains well how you can provide a Service to do the mapping with Jackson.

In order to make this work with MapStruct you can use [qualifiers](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#selection-based-on-qualifiers) and annotate your service accordingly.

For example

```
@Qualifier // from the MapStruct package
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)
public @interface FromJson {
}

public interface StringToMapConverter {

    @FromJson
    Map<String, String> convert(String string);
}

@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface MyMapper {

    @Mapping(target = "storyInfo", qualifiedBy = FromJson.class)
    StoryDTO convert(Story story);
}
```

The implementation of `StringToMapConverter` should be as in the already provided answer. You don't have to use a dedicated interface for the converter, you an also use an abstract mapper, inject the `ObjectMapper` and do the rest same.

MapStruct will then use it to convert the `storyInfo` `String` into the map.

Some other possible solution, outside of the scope of the question and if you use Hibernate. You can use `Map<String, String>` in your entity, but still map it to String in the DB. Have a look at [hibernate-types](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types/) by Vlad Mihalcea, it allows using extra types so you can persist objects as JSON in the database

Answer (score 1):

1. You can create a generic tool class so other Mapper can also use.

   p.s: JsonUtil just a util clss use to transform Object to Json.

   And you can use jackson, fastjson, gson.

```
@Component
public class MapStructUtil {

    @Qualifier
    @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    public @interface JsonStrToMap {

    }

    @Qualifier
    @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.SOURCE)
    public @interface MapToJsonStr {

    }

    @JsonStrToMap
    public Map jsonStrToMap(String jsonStr) {
        return JsonUtil.toMap(jsonStr);
    }

    @MapToJsonStr
    public String mapToJsonStr(Map<String, String> map) {
        return JsonUtil.toJsonString(map);
    }
}
```

2. Then you can use it in your Mapper like this

p.s: Here use componentModel = "spring", so you need to add @Componnent annotation in MapStructUtil

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", uses = {MapStructUtil.class})
public interface StoryMapper {

      @Mapping(source = "storyInfo", target = "storyInfo", qualifiedBy = JsonStrToMap.class)
      StoryDTO toStoryDTO(Story story);

      @Mapping(source = "storyInfo", target = "storyInfo", qualifiedBy = MapToJsonStr.class)
      Story toStory(StoryDTO storyDTO);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `MapStruct`, but I might suggest an alternative since you are running your application in a Spring context.

Since your string is a JSON string, your best course of action would be to use a JSON library. Spring Boot comes with its own preconfigued instance of the Jackson `ObjectMapper` (which you may override to add/remove specific features by defining using a `@Bean` of type `ObjectMapper` in any `@Configuration` class).

You might inject an instance of this using:

```
@Autowired
ObjectMapper objectMapper;
```

After that, you are able to use the object mapper to transform the string into a `HashMap<String, String>` (or whichever types you need) as follows:

```
Map<String, String> result = objectMapper.readValue(storyInfo, new TypeReference<Map<String, String>>() {});
```

I will try to update this answer with a `MapStruct` approach, but perhaps this might be more practical for you at this time.

Comment: I have provided a MapStruct approach. You can have a look at it and update your answer accordingly. Your answer is completely OK, and the OP would need to implement something like that so the string can be eventually converted